# FileInputStream.read() vs FileOutputStream.write()

Tags: java, io, stream

I tried to make a simple program that copies a file. According to the documentation, `FileInputStream.read()` and `FileOuputStream.write()` seemed similar to me. They read and write an `int`, from and to a file, respectively. So then, why does the following not work?

```
import java.io.*;

class CopyFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream original = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        FileOutputStream copy = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
        while (original.read() != -1) {
            copy.write(original.read());
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting file is totally different from the original. Why isn't this working as I expected?

Comment: Just for the sake of it, you are aware of the existence of the [`Files.copy'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) methods?

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding and just wanted to see if I understood basic IO, but thanks for bringing my attention to that!

Comment: ok, are you aware that you don't close your OutputStream so it *may* cause incomplete data as not all data might be flushed? Use ["try-with-resources"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for both `original` and `copy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your code:

```
    while (original.read() != -1) {
        copy.write(original.read());
    }
```

You read one byte to test if it's end of file, then you read another byte to write.

Hence the byte you read in `while` condition is skipped.

The correct way is:

```
    int b;
    while ((b=original.read()) != -1) {
        copy.write(b);
    }
```